# how to kill the pawn from enemy in ludo, using flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am new to flash, and I have created a ludo design ,plz give me solution how to kill 
      the pawn from another enemy pawn and after killed the pawn set back to home position.

Comment: It seems you ask someone to write your code.

Comment: Mr.helloflash I am not asking anyone to write my code. I am asking for suggestions or ideas.

Comment: Gottidre haku ,illandre ......muchkondu iru...

Comment: Well what does "kill the pawn" mean exactly?? You mean like  `stage.removeChild(objectName)` where _objectName_ is the sprite/movieClip to remove from screen? You position things using `objectName.x` and `objectName.y`. Maybe better to show the part of your code that you need help with so we can advise...